# Drizzle ORM BLOB column data type in MySQL

Tags: drizzle

I want to create a BLOB data type to store a PDF file which unknown file size. How can I create BLOB column in Drizzle?

The closest data types supported by Drizzle are `BINARY` and `VARBINARY` (see [here](https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/column-types/mysql)) which require the max length. Meaning I need to specify a maximum size and hoping that user will not store a PDF bigger than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How abou to use Varbinary in mysql?

https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/column-types/mysql#varbinary

since it says in the [Mysql Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html).

> In most respects, you can regard a BLOB column as a VARBINARY column
> that can be as large as you like.